# How do I show a successful compile in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

All,

I have ran my program and compiled it successfully using Eclipse. Our professor wants a screen shot of some sort of text showing that it "compiled successfully" even though the output screen shows that it did, he is looking for something more. In the IDE jGRASP it gives you a message saying "jGRASP Operation Complete." How do I get something similar in Eclipse?

I have provided the screenshot of my modified source code and a screenshot of the full and successful output. I am baffled on how I am supposed to supply some sort of notification. Any thoughts?

Thank you,

Prog

Comment: Compile it on the command line, and run it - should do the trick.  (S)he'll see that there's no errors from the compiler.  Unless it *has* to be in Eclipse...

Comment: I'm flagging this as "unclear what you're asking" through no fault of yours - It's unclear to me what your professor wants from you!

Comment: I just gave in, downloaded jGRASP, compiled it, got the message needed and sent him a screenshot of it compiled in both jGRASP and Eclipse. Our professor is incredibly unclear for the requirements of most of his assignments unfortunately. It's a constant question and answer game for most of us in the class to get more clarity.

Comment: I would have circled the ".class" files in the "bin" folder.